# Should {tp_alloc, tp_dealloc} and {tp_new, tp_free} be considered as pairs?

Tags: c++, python-c-api, pycxx

Is it true that whatever is created in tp_alloc should be destroyed in tp_dealloc?  And similarly for {tp_new, tp_free}?

It looks like an obvious symmetry, but I would be grateful for clarification.

---

My actual use case is this:
I have:

```
class OSClass : PyObject {...}

class Final : OSClass {...}
```

So the corresponding `PyTypeObject pto` has:

```
pto->tp_basicsize = sizeof(FinalClass)
pto->tp_dealloc = (destructor) 
                  [](PyObject* pyob) { PyMem_Free(pyob); };
```

However the new style class stores the PyObject and its corresponding C++ object separately from one another, and therefore works differently.

It creates the PyObject in tp_new, and the corresponding C++ object in tp_init.

And destroys both of them in tp_dealloc

Is this correct/optimal?

Code:

```
// extra void* to point to corresponding C++ object
pto->tp_basicsize = sizeof(PyObject) + sizeof(void*)

pto->tp_new = new_func;
pto->tp_init = init_func;
pto->tp_dealloc = dealloc_func;

static PyObject* new_func( PyTypeObject* subtype, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwds )
{
    // First we create the Python object.
    // The type-object's tp_basicsize is set to sizeof(Bridge)
    // (Note: We could maybe use PyType_GenericNew for this:
    //   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/573275/python-c-api-object-allocation )
    //
    PyObject* pyob = subtype->tp_alloc(subtype,0);

    Bridge* bridge = reinterpret_cast<Bridge*>(pyob);

    // We construct the C++ object later in init_func (below)
    bridge->m_pycxx_object = nullptr;

    return pyob;
}


static int init_func( PyObject* self, PyObject* args, PyObject* kwds )
{
    try
    {
        Object a = to_tuple(args);
        Object k = to_dict(kwds);

        Bridge* bridge{ reinterpret_cast<Bridge*>(self) };

        // NOTE: observe this is where we invoke the 
        //       constructor, but indirectly (i.e. through final)
        bridge->m_pycxx_object = new FinalClass{ bridge, a, k };
    }
    catch( Exception & )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

static void dealloc_func( PyObject* pyob )
{
    auto final = static_cast<FinalClass*>( cxxbase_for(pyob) );

    delete final;
    PyMem_Free(pyob);

    COUT( "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" );
    //self->ob_type->tp_free(self);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [`tp_new` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_new) you have

> The **tp_new** function should call `subtype->tp_alloc(subtype, nitems)` to allocate space for the object, and then do only as much further initialization as is absolutely necessary. Initialization that can safely be ignored or repeated should be placed in the **tp_init** handler. A good rule of thumb is that for immutable types, all initialization should take place in **tp_new**, while for mutable types, most initialization should be deferred to **tp_init**.

That's why you create the object itself in `tp_new` and initialise it in `tp_init`. Creating the C++ object is part of the initialisation. Since the [`tp_init` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_init) states

> This function corresponds to the **__init__**() method of classes. Like **__init__**(), it is possible to create an instance without calling **__init__**(), and it is possible to reinitialize an instance by calling its **__init__**() method again.

You need to check for `bridge->m_pycxx_object != nullptr` and delete the already initialised instance on failure or raise an error.

In `tp_dealloc` you then destroy the Python object. Since the C++ object is part of this one, it needs to be destroyed there as well.

---

Back to the pairing: You call `tp_alloc` within `tp_new` and `tp_free` within `tp_dealloc`. So {`tp_alloc`, `tp_free`} and {`tp_new`, `tp_dealloc`} should be considered as pairs.